# Simple c++ program

Tags: c++

Could you tell me where is the error and why when I execute the program, random numbers are displayed?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int total;

    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    double x1;
    cin >> x1;
    total = total + x1;

    cout << "total: " << total << endl;
    cout << "Please enter a number: ";

    double x2;
    cin >> x2;
    total = total + x2;
    cout << "total: " << total << endl;

    total = total / 2;
    cout << "total: " << total << endl;
    cout << "The average is " << total << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Where do you thing the problem is?

Comment: You failed to initialize `total`. Use `int total = 0;`.

Comment: Start with `int total = 0;`

Comment: You're missing an initialization of total to 0. Since you just use total it contains any value which is quite random. Instead of `int total;` write `int total = 0;`

Comment: Compile with `-Wall`, and you may see why

Comment: @LukasThomsen: Actually using an uninitialized variable as an R-value invokes undefined behavior. The compiler may do anything if it sees that, including (but not limited) to emitting a program, that wipes all the storage in the computer.

Comment: @datenwolf I agree to your statement but the undefined behavior results from the memory of the variable not being initialized. When the application is loaded `total` gets a place in memory. This memory can contain any value depending on what the memory was previously used for. Therefore the value of `total` is undefined and may change each time you execute the application looking random for the application.

Comment: @LukasThomsen: That's just one way how undefined behavior may manifest. UB is UB and **anything** can happen. It has nothing to do with the "variable being placed somewhere". If the compiler sees, that a value is read from an uninitialized variable it may **and will** do really weird stuff. Random values poping up  are the least of your problems. Recommended read (also C++) http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html – http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html – http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html

Answer (score 2):

Variable `total` is not initialized. Must initialize it first before you use it, like this:

```
int total = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for bad editing, I am new to programming!